# Pine Script - Cross Buy and Sell plots

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

```
longCond = bool(na)
shortCond = bool(na)
longCond := source > filt and source > source[1] and upward > 0 or source > filt and source < source[1] and upward > 0
shortCond := source < filt and source < source[1] and downward > 0 or source < filt and source > source[1] and downward > 0

CondIni = 0
CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]

long = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
short = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

plotshape(long, title="Long", text="Long", style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.black, size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, transp=0)
plotshape(short, title="Short", text="Short", style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.white, size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0)
```

Hello

I am trying to make this script plot long1 & long2 and short1 & short2

ex) long1 -> short1 -> long2 -> short2 -> long1 -> short1 and so on.

Is it possible to make this using pine script?

Thank you.

Tried to make cross signal plots.

Comment: What is long1, short1, long2 and short2 ... How it is defined is your code ?

Comment: This script only showing long and short plots, so long1 and long2 are actually same condition. I am trying to make modification to mark numbers on each plots. long1 -> short1 -> long2 -> short2 -> long1 -> short1